# Does an integral operator with a symmetric integrable kernel have to be bounded on $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-operators

Suppose $K(x,y)$ is a symmetric kernel. Let $\phi\in L^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ everywhere is a domain in $R^n$. 
Can $\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\,\phi(y)\,dy$ belong to $L^2$? 
In other words can an inequality of the type 
$$
\left\|\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\,\phi(y)\,dy\right\|_{2} \leq \|K\|_{L^1(\Omega\times\Omega)} \|\varphi\|_{2}
$$
exist?

Comment: By Holder's inequality, it holds $\left\|\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\,\phi(y)\,dy\right\|_{2} \leq \|K\|_{L^2(\Omega\times\Omega)} \|\varphi\|_{2}$. So, if you assume that $K \in L^2(\Omega\times \Omega)$, then it will be ok.

Comment: @ Voliar...I was looking for an inequality if $K\in L_{loc}^1$. Can you please help me?

Comment: If $K \in L^1_{loc}$, then it is not the fact that $\|K\|_{L^1(\Omega\times \Omega)} < +\infty$. You should clarify the settings.

Comment: In my set up $\Omega$ is a closed and bounded region. So $L_{loc}^1$ or $L^1$ makes no difference. Can you help me out with this set up to obtain an inequality or at least a way to guarantee that the integral transform defined by $\int K(x,y)\phi(y)dy$ is a mapping between $L^2$ to itself?.(you may disprove me also).

Comment: Just consider $f(x) = 1/x$. Then $f \in L^1_{loc}(0,1)$, but $f \not \in L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: So, if you assume that $K \in L^1_{loc}$, then it is not so hard to find the counterexample like $K(x,y) = 1/(x y)$.

Comment: sorry for my naivity...

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample even if $K \in L^1(\Omega \times \Omega)$.

Consider $K(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$. And $\Omega \times \Omega = (0,1) \times (0,1)$.
Put $\varphi \equiv 1$ in $(0,1)$. It is clear that $\varphi \in L^2(0,1)$.
Then
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dy\right)^2 dx = 
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \left( \int_0^1  \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dy\right)^2 dx = 
4 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \left( \sqrt{y}|_0^1 \right)^2 dx = \\
4 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = +\infty.
$$

(it is also clear, that $K \in L^1(\Omega \times \Omega)$, since
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dx dy = \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx \right)^2 = constant)
$$

Comment: I was trying to come up with an inequality of the above type with $K(x,y)$ being the derivative of the Green's function of the Laplacian. In the process I found that the derivative belongs to $L_{loc}^1$. I was trying to then look for an inequality of the type asked in my question. Thanks for pointing out the flaws. At least is it possible for the inequality to hold with $K$ being the derivative of the Green's function of the Laplacian?.

Comment: @Alexander As far as I remember, Green's function has different asymptotic in singularity point, depending on the dimension of the domain $\Omega$. So, probably it is possible in some cases, but I'm not sure.

Comment: OK...ThankS FOR ALL YOUR REPLIES...